# Fill out an xlsx table with xlsx4j in Java

Tags: excel, docx4j

I need to fill out two worksheets in an existing xlsx file. In the first one, I have a pivot table set up and linked to a table called `myTable` in the second sheet.

In the template, `myTable` has only a header and an empty row (so two rows). I need to fill out `myTable` with `X` rows but I do not manage to do it. When I append rows to the worksheet it doesn't add them to `myTable` but below it. So the data are not used for the pivot table.

Does someone have a solution to fill out a table or resize it with xlsx4j (docx4j) library or maybe another Java library?

Thanks for all,
Benoît